How to use current user credentials in published Power BI report against Snowflake?
We are using Power BI as our reporting and dashboard tool for our Snowflake data warehouse. WE have a need for a published report to use the credentials of the person calling the report rather than the person who created and published the report, and have been unable to determine a way of doing this.
We have two data visibility restrictions that need to be enforced. First, based on the user's role, they are limited as to what columns of data they can see; we're enforcing this with a data masking policy in Snowflake. Second, we have a need to restrict which rows are visible to certain individuals based on their role; we have a row access policy in Snowflake which determines through a user-defined function call what customers' data are visible to a user.
Both of these work in perfectly well in Snowflake, but when called from Power BI, the data returned is based on the user who published and shared the report rather than the one executing it.
Is there a way to pass through the calling user's ID instead of the publisher's?
Additional information:
We are using Direct Query in a published report to try and get results filtered and masked results based on the calling user's role.
Person A has the ability to view all 7 columns on a table.
Person B has the ability to see 5 of these columns
Person C has the ability to see 4 of these columns, but only where the value of column 1 is within a certain group of values
Person D has the ability to see 4 of these columns, but only where the value of column 1 is within a certain group of values that is different from the values seen by Person C.
Person A creates a report that shows all 7 columns for all rows.
We have masking rules that replace values that replace values for columns that are not in a user's allowed column list with "REDACTED"
We also have a row access policy that looks up a user's list of allowed values for column 1 and filters visible rows based on that list.
We have been unable to get the report to use anything other than the publisher's access, which exposes legally sensitive information.
